# Reward Bounty among 2 Users

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I have this question on ServerFault: [Weird Apache Access Logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/602248/weird-apache-access-logs)

I think both the answers have helped me equally. And i would like to divide the bounty equally amongst them.

I don't think there would be any provisions for this. But what are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I've been in this situation before, and I gave it to the person with the lowest rep, just to be sporting :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't award a single bounty to two users, but you can always create a second bounty once you've awarded the first one, and then award that one to the second user. There is even a specific bounty reason for this:

[image: Reward existing answer: One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.]

You will, of course, [need a little extra reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) in order to do this.

Comment: So i've awarded the bounty to one user. But i don't see an option to create another bounty. I have 50+ reputation. Shouldn't it be showing me that option?

Comment: No, you need 75 reputation to be able to offer a bounty.

Comment: @user38480 You can [earn 100 rep points](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) in the blink of on eye

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Have more than 75 now. But still not able to offer a second bounty. :(

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible now to be honest, but it's very nice of you to care. That said not many people really give too much of a toss about their rep these days, not for one accept anyway.